# Tool to open >4GB .zip file created by .NET System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory

Tags: .net, compression, zip

We need to create huge zip files programaticaly in .NET. Currently we use the STL System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory function, which works great, however when the target archive file is greater than 4GB, all archiving tools (including built-in windows zip support) cannot correctly open it and think it's corrupted. I tried also quite few tools supporting zip64 format (7zip, TUGZip, DotNetZip library etc.) but they also see it as corrupted.

I'm still able to extract it by with System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory function. However I'd like to avoid reinventing the wheel and writing my own tool for extracting selected files from archive (extracting it completely everytime when just 1 log is needed would be unacceptable)

Are you aware of any (preferably free) tool that can open zip archives greater than 4GB created by ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory? Or even existing code  snippets for very simple extractor of choosen files using ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory.

Comment: Are you sure that the decompression is the problem? With so many tools saying the archive is corrupt it maybe really is and the .NET compression is the real problem?

Comment: Have you considered using DotNetZip for compression? I'm assuming that its ZIP64 support works correctly and can be opened by other tools?

Comment: @cremor I can always successfully decompress the archive with the complement function (ExtractToDirectory) without any problems. So the archive is not definitely corrupted - it's just that the tools that I used doesn't 'understand' it's format.
Also this problem occurs only for archives bigger then ~ 4GB

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for suggestion.
I've been considering and bit experimenting with DetNetZip, SharpZipLib and one other. However our current code is one-liner with no dependency on third party code/libraries - we first need to be sure that there is no other workaround (and even then we'd probably choose to write small proprietary decompress tool using System.IO.Compression functionality) - as cost (current and ongoing) associated with linking third party lib/code (especially now - after deployment) needs to be also considered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory.
I've blogged about this here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jankrivanek/archive/2013/08/07/bug-in-zipfile-createfromdirectory-your-archive-can-be-irreparable-corrupted.aspx
Appropriate team in Microsoft is working on a fix.